# jQuery hide/show 2 menus

Tags: jquery, html, menu

Good day everyone!

I am having the following issue: I have a menu for one product and another menu for another product. It goes something like this:

Product1 | Product2

Home Option1 Option2 Option3 | Option1 Option2 Option3

where first 3 options are for Product1 and the last 3 options are for Product2. I only need to see the menu for one product.

My HTML goes smth like this (simplified of course):

```
<div class="products">
<a href="#" id="product1">Product1</a>
<a href="#" id="product2">Product2</a>
</div>
<ul id="menu1">
<li>Option1</li>
<li>Option2</li>
<li>Option3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu2">
<li>Option1</li>
<li>Option2</li>
<li>Option3</li>
</ul>
```

And jQuery goes smth like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#product1").addClass("active");
    $("#menu2").hide();

    $("#product2").click(function () {
         $("#menu1").hide();
         $("#menu2").show();
         $("#product1").removeClass("active");
         $("#product2").addClass("active");
    });
    $("#product1").click(function () {
         $("#menu2").hide();
         $("#menu1").show();
         $("#product2").removeClass("active");
         $("#product1").addClass("active");
    });
 });
```

**Problem:** When I first load the page everything is ok. When I click on #product2 for instance, it does everything that is specified in the function:

```
 $("#product2").click(function () {
         $("#menu1").hide();
         $("#menu2").show();
         $("#product1").removeClass("active");
         $("#product2").addClass("active");
    });
```

but it also executes the first two lines:

```
    $("#product1").addClass("active");
    $("#menu2").hide();
```

And I get both #product1 and #product2 active and both menus hidden. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like your exemple works fine ... http://jsfiddle.net/d7DrG/

Comment: it does on jsfiddle, but it doesn't in my web project. may be I should have mentioned it's in a ASP.NET Web Forms project. the behaviour looks weird to me as well, but I can't find the reason behind it.

Comment: Can you try debbuging with some break points, watching step by step where your code goes after you click ? This code is much simple, and the error still weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent the default action for the click events by returning false. This way, your page will not be reloaded.

Something like this should do the trick :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#product1").addClass("active");
    $("#menu2").hide();

    $("#product2").click(function () {
        $("#menu1").hide();
        $("#menu2").show();
        $("#product1").removeClass("active");
        $("#product2").addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
    $("#product1").click(function () {
        $("#menu2").hide();
        $("#menu1").show();
        $("#product2").removeClass("active");
        $("#product1").addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The page is not reloaded when navigating to `#`

Comment: It shouldn't reload, but with return false everything works just fine. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You need to add `return false` to your functions.

**Extra info:**

At the start of your script you have the following:

```
$("#product1").addClass("active");
$("#menu2").hide();
```

I would be inclined to assign these properties in the HTML or CSS somewhere, so that `product1` has the `active` class, etc.

Finally, have you considered just using a jQuery Accordion or Tabstrip component?

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Word from the wise: WebForms is not very accommodating of client-side scripting like this. It tries to grab every click, keypress, etc for itself via the ViewState. Nasty stuff.